# Why is the operator / function conversion not reversible?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell every operator is considered to be syntactic sugar for a two-argument function (except unary minus, which is a lexical-level exception).

I can convert an operator into a function by enclosing it in brackets, like this:

```
Prelude> (+) 3 4
7
```

Likewise I can make a two-argument function into an operator by enclosing it in back-ticks:

```
Prelude> 3 `max` 4
4
```

So why can't I do both?

```
Prelude> (`max`) 3 4
<interactive>:3:7: error: parse error on input ‘)’

Prelude> 3 `(+)` 4
<interactive>:4:4: error: parse error on input ‘(’
```

The first is particularly egregious because the following does work:

```
Prelude> (`max` 3) 4
4
```

Comment: It's not a conversion operator; it's pure syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every time you write `` (`max`) ``, you could also write `max`. Every time you write `` `(+)` `` you could also write `+`. Making the syntax of operators or identifiers recursive adds complexity to the parser for no benefit.

```
op ::= opSymbol* | `identifier`
```

Comment: Also note that it's ``( `identifier` )`` instead of ``( `expression` )``. The latter could lead to some weird cases to parse, since the expression might involve backticks e.g. ``( a `\x y -> x `max` y` b )``.

Comment: @chi ...which is why I have sometimes wished there was a properly "open- and close-paren" version of them. Currently the character pairs backtick-open-paren and close-paren-backtick are invalid syntax, so you could make them valid without breaking backward compatibility, and it would sometimes be nice to be able to make an expression be infix briefly.